# Посыпался дизайн адаптивного меню

Tags: css, css3

По этой ссылке - codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMXbGp, можно увидеть тестовую страничку с адаптивным меню. Для пк все отображается нормально.

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
      
      var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
        title: "Menu",
        format: "dropdown",
        sticky: false
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
        cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
        if (settings.format != 'select') {
          cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
          $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
              mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
            }
            else {
              mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });

          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
              }
              else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
              }
            });
          };

          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
        }

        else if (settings.format === 'select')
        {
          cssmenu.append('<select style="width: 100%"/>').addClass('select-list');
          var selectList = cssmenu.find('select');
          selectList.append('<option>' + settings.title + '</option>', {
                                                         "selected": "selected",
                                                         "value": ""});
          cssmenu.find('a').each(function() {
            var element = $(this), indentation = "";
            for (i = 1; i < element.parents('ul').length; i++)
            {
              indentation += '-';
            }
            selectList.append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + indentation + element.text() + '</option');
          });
          selectList.on('change', function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
          });
        }

        if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

        resizeFix = function() {
          if ($(window).width() > settings.breakpoint) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            cssmenu.removeClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').hide();
            }
            else {
              cssmenu.find("#menu-button").removeClass("menu-opened");
            }
          }

          if ($(window).width() <= settings.breakpoint && !cssmenu.hasClass("small-screen")) {
            cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            cssmenu.addClass('small-screen');
            if (settings.format === 'select') {
              cssmenu.find('select').show();
            }
          }
        };
        resizeFix();
        return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

      });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   title: "Menu",
   format: "multitoggle"
});

});
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body{
 font: 16px Calibri;
 background: #d2d2d2 url(../img/bg.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

#wrapper{
 background: #f3f3f3;
 box-shadow: 0 0 21px rgba(0,0,0,.22);
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#content{
 padding-left: 18px;
 padding-right: 18px;
 padding-bottom: 0.1px;
}

/* Горизонтальная верхняя навигация */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
 background: #F3E5D1;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#F3E5D1), color-stop(34%,#F3E5D1), color-stop(94%,#E7C69B), color-stop(100%,#c19c9c));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F3E5D1 0%,#F3E5D1 34%,#E7C69B 94%,#c19c9c 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F3E5D1 0%,#F3E5D1 34%,#E7C69B 94%,#c19c9c 100%);
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child{
 border-left: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  border-left: 1px solid #a5a5a0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
height:35px;
line-height: 35px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
 color: #ffffff;
background: #4a87c8;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
/* Убираем плюсик
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #84847e;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #84847e;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
*/
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {

  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
height: auto;
background: #F3E5D1;

text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu ul ul li a{
 line-height: 36px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
  height: 35px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {

  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {

  height: 100%;
color: #000;

   /*font-size: 12px; 
     padding: 15px;
  background: #F3E5D1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
   */
  text-decoration: none;



}

#cssmenu ul > ul > li > a {

 /* padding: 11px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  font-size: 12px;*/
  text-decoration: none;

  font-weight: 400;
  /* background: #333333;*/
  
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li ul li{
 width: 455px;
 height: 36px !important;
 background: #F3E5D1;
 outline: 1px solid #a5a5a0;
}

#cssmenu ul li ul li ul li:hover{
 background: #e4e2cd;
}


#cssmenu ul li ul li ul li a{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 13px Georgia;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.menu-line-height{
   /*line-height: 23px !important;*/
}

#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}


#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}

@media(min-width:1200px){
    #wrapper{
        width:850px;
    }
 
 #cssmenu > ul > li {
  width: 170px;
 }
 
 #cssmenu ul ul li a{
  width: 169px;
 
 }
 
 #cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 170px !important;
 }

}

@media(min-width:1000px) and (max-width:1200px){
    #wrapper{
        width:760px;
    }
 
 #cssmenu > ul > li{
  width: 152px;
 }
 
 #cssmenu ul ul li a{
  width: 151.5px;
 }
 
 #cssmenu ul ul ul {
   margin-left: 152px;
 }
}

@media (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1000px){
 #wrapper{
  width: 590px;
 }
}

@media(min-width:481px) and (max-width:768px){
    #wrapper{
        width:420px;
    }
}

/* Стили для мобильного меню */
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
 /* Убираем иконки */
 #main, #lib, #url, #questions, #reviews{
  display: none;
 }
 
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
 background: #474d59;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    /*padding-left: 25px;*/
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
   /* padding-left: 35px; */
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
 color:#fff;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
   /* width: 46px; */
 width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
   /* background: #262626; */
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
    height: 34px;
   /* width: 34px; */
 width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 15px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '+';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 12px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
  
  #cssmenu ul li ul li ul li a {
 width: 100%;
 }
 
 #cssmenu > ul > li > a{
  color: #fff;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='#'><span id="main"></span>Главная</a></li>
  <li class='active'><a href='javascript:void(0);'><span id="lib"></span><span class="lib-correct">Архив</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href='javascript:void(0);'><span class="arch-hover">Книги</span></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>1</a> </li>
      <li><a href='#'><span class="menu-line-height">2</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span class="menu-line-height">3</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>4</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'><span class="menu-line-height">5</span></a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>6</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>7</a></li>
     </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href='#'><span class="arch-hover">Видео</span></a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'><span id="url"></span>Ссылки</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><span id="questions"></span>Вопросы</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'><span id="reviews"></span>Отзывы</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<div id="content">

<p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc lacinia bibendum ante nec scelerisque. Ut pharetra auctor congue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce aliquet diam arcu, sit amet tincidunt risus fermentum quis. Sed laoreet accumsan neque ut efficitur. In augue elit, consectetur nec placerat sit amet, sodales eget leo. Morbi at ipsum lacus. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Aenean id commodo nisi, vel commodo enim. Quisque eu ligula id sem dignissim malesuada ac ut elit. Vestibulum nec sem quis tellus vehicula porttitor a eu sem. Integer a euismod odio. Nam mattis fermentum hendrerit. Donec enim ex, dignissim sit amet auctor sollicitudin, aliquet non orci. Donec rhoncus gravida dignissim.
<br><br>
Mauris iaculis odio quam, in lobortis ex lacinia eu. Aliquam faucibus a odio ac lacinia. In sed risus at metus vulputate dapibus. Suspendisse at quam a lectus consequat cursus ac sit amet ex. Morbi viverra a quam eget varius. Fusce aliquet dolor a sodales egestas. Ut tincidunt erat et erat dictum, sit amet vestibulum leo maximus. Maecenas pretium nibh purus, et efficitur arcu consectetur sit amet. Ut sagittis tempus tempus. Nam lobortis malesuada arcu et facilisis. Nunc mattis, velit nec tincidunt bibendum, nisl sapien dapibus nibh, in lacinia ante augue ut ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```

На самом codepen при активации мобильной версии показывает это - скриншот с нормальной высотой пунктов. То что подпункты вылазят за границу не страшно, сам поправлю.
На локальном компе вот это - второй скриншот, высота пунктов становиться огромной.
С помощью инспектора кода нашел:

```
#cssmenu ul ul li, #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {height: auto;}
```

, удалил высоту. Пункты стали нормальной высоты, однако появилась другая каша, когда наводишь курсор на "Книги". Третий скриншот смотрите. 
Помогите пожалуйста! Как это исправить? У меня уже мозг плавится от анализа!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У #cssmenu ul li Уберите position: relative. 
Это должно исправить ситуацию на третьем скриншоте.